# Magnetic field in different medium

Tags: magnetic-fields

[image]

To solve this question we apply the same concept as that of light that the component of magnetic field which is perpendicular to the surface will be same in different medium .

But I could not understand the concept(reason) behind it.

Comment: When you do what you suggest (demanding that the perpendicular components of $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{B}'$ are equal), which of the four answers do you get? The interface conditions for electromagnetic fields, which is what you are talking about, solve this pretty unambiguously.

Comment: @WojciechMorawiec then the option 3 should be the answer  . But I want to know the concept behind it . Why they are equal.

Comment: Ah, could you in that case edit the question to ask why they equal? Because right now, you are asking whether you can apply concept X and the answer to that is "yes".